# Why have some of my questions been deleted from my activity/inbox, while others remain?

Tags: discussion

Why have some of my questions been deleted from my activity/inbox?  I have some closed questions still there.

Answer (score 1):

Closed questions are automatically deleted if they meet certain criteria, and there isn't really anything we can do about it. See this Meta discussion: [Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered, zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/256282)

Was there a particular question you needed the link for? Or did you just want to know where they have gone?

Comment: just where they have gone and why they have been deleted (not been 1 year) and why some if not others

Comment: @anothertheory The post details all the criteria that will result in a question being deleted - it can happen after only nine days after a question that was closed. It also explains why Stack Exchange staff think such questions should not remain and fill search results.

Comment: Ok thanks for your response